# Logback - How to log the simple name of an exception separately

Tags: java, spring, logging, logback, slf4j

Is there any way you can log only the simple name of an exception **without explicitly retrieving it from the code?**

For example, by calling

```
log.error(exception);
```

with a logback pattern

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd}|%-5level|%m%n
```

instead of just logging the exception stack traces

```
2018-01-01|ERROR|
mainPackage.foo.bar.RocketExplosionException: Houston we have a problem
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire(TestThrower.java:22)
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.readyToLaunch(TestThrower.java:17)
  at mainPackage.ExceptionLauncher.main(ExceptionLauncher.java:38)
```

A separate column with the simple name of the exception is expected to be logged

```
2018-01-01|ERROR|RocketExplosionException|
mainPackage.foo.bar.RocketExplosionException: Houston we have a problem
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire(TestThrower.java:22)
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.readyToLaunch(TestThrower.java:17)
  at mainPackage.ExceptionLauncher.main(ExceptionLauncher.java:38)
```

Comment: You can implement your own `Layout` instead of using `PatternLayout`.

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, but I found that it's quite difficult to both keep the original `PatternLayout` syntax and support the new feature on exception names, especially when the pattern is rather complicated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write your own [custom conversion specifier](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#customConversionSpecifier).

To do this, you would declare a conversion rule in your `logback.xml` for the `%exname` symbolic like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <conversionRule conversionWord="exname" converterClass="com.foo.ExceptionNameConverter" />

    ...

</configuration>
```

Then declare `ExceptionNameConverter` like so:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.pattern.ThrowableProxyConverter;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.IThrowableProxy;

public class ExceptionNameConverter extends ThrowableProxyConverter {
    @Override
    protected String throwableProxyToString(IThrowableProxy tp) {
        return tp.getClassName();
    }
}
```

Now, using this pattern:

```
%d{yyyy-MM-dd}|%-5level|%exname|%m%n
```

The following log statement:

```
logger.error("Boom!", new RuntimeException("ouch"));
```

Will emit:

```
2018-09-26|ERROR|java.lang.RuntimeException|Boom!
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. And to print stack trace as well, the pattern could be modified to `%d{yyyy-MM-dd}|%-5level|%exname|%m%n%ex`

Comment: Yes, `%ex` gives you the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

As is Andreas suggests, one way to support exception name logging is use a custom `Layout` instead of `PatternLayout`

A sample layout:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.IThrowableProxy;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ThrowableProxyUtil;
import ch.qos.logback.core.CoreConstants;
import ch.qos.logback.core.LayoutBase;

public class ErrorLoggingLayout extends LayoutBase<ILoggingEvent> {

    private static final char SEP = '|';

    @Override
    public String doLayout(final ILoggingEvent event) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
        sb.append(event.getTimeStamp() - event.getLoggerContextVO().getBirthTime());
        sb.append(SEP);
        sb.append(event.getLevel());
        sb.append(SEP);
        sb.append(event.getThreadName());
        sb.append(SEP);
        StackTraceElement frame = event.getCallerData()[0];
        sb.append(extractSimpleName(frame.getClassName())).append('.').append(frame.getMethodName()).append(':').append(frame.getLineNumber());
        sb.append(SEP);
        IThrowableProxy throwableProxy = event.getThrowableProxy();
        if (throwableProxy != null) {
            String simpleName = extractSimpleName(throwableProxy.getClassName());
            sb.append(simpleName);
        }
        sb.append(SEP);
        sb.append(event.getFormattedMessage());
        sb.append(CoreConstants.LINE_SEPARATOR);
        if (throwableProxy != null) {
            sb.append(ThrowableProxyUtil.asString(throwableProxy));
        }
        return sb.toString();

    }

    @NotNull
    private String extractSimpleName(final String cName) {
        int index = cName.lastIndexOf('.');
        return cName.substring(index + 1);
    }
}
```

This result turns out like

```
7645|ERROR|Thread-Name-0|RocketConsole.report:22|RocketExplosionException|custom msg
mainPackage.foo.bar.RocketExplosionException: Houston we have a problem
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire(TestThrower.java:22)
  at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.readyToLaunch(TestThrower.java:17)
  at mainPackage.ExceptionLauncher.main(ExceptionLauncher.java:38)
```

However, one shortage of this approach is that the output format might be slightly different than the original pattern, and it takes extra effort to format the fields.